# How to read from text file into two dimensional array and print it in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, import

Hello I am currently learning c++ in school and have a project on it and need some help.

I have to make a program that reads the number of seats and stores it in a two dimensional array. The empty seats is hashtag and if the user buys a seat it becomes *. The odd number of rows in the seats.txt file have 15 seats and even ones have 20.

I want to be able to print this and update it when the user buys a seat and switch # with *.

The seats txt file looks like this:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #     
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #     
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #     
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #     
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #     
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #     
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #     
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Here is my code:

```
const char EMPTY = '#';
char ab[15][20];
ifstream in;
in.open("seats.txt");
for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
    for(int x=0; x<20; x++){
           in>>ab[i][x];

    }
}

for (int i = -1; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -1; j < columns; j++)
                ab [i][j] = EMPTY;
        }

for (int count = 0; count < 15; count++)
        {
            cout << endl << "Row " << (count + 1);
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 <20; count2++)
            {
                cout << "  " <<  ab[count] [count2];
            }
        }
            cout << endl;
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?   and please review [mre]   200 lines is not so minimal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you want the array representing the first row to have length 15? Or do you want that array to have length 20 (like the second row) but use only the first 15 elements to represent the row of 15 seats?

Comment: At the top of this page is a search box (spy glass symobol).  If you type "read text into 2 dimensional"  there are many examples of similar coding efforts.

Comment: I want to have to be able to print the chart of the seats available just like it is in the text file using 2d arrays. The first row is 0 and it has 20 seats while the odd row 1 has 15.

Comment: If you have an array of length 20, such as `char x[20];`, do you know how to put 15 elements into it, and then read them out?

Comment: Yea i can do that using for loop.

Comment: All right, you know how to iterate over an even row, and you know how to iterate over an odd row, so you know how to iterate over all 15 rows. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that with the code that I have written I do not seem to be able to print the seat arrangement. I can print particular element using cout<<ab[x][y] but cannot print the whole file.

Comment: 1) It helps if you give the output your program produces; see our [intro pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). 2) When your program doesn't work, *try something simpler.* Can you read and print the first row of seats?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. E.g. what is `rows`? And please format your code before you post it here. Most IDE/editors can do it for you. You can also use format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: Why do you start the loops with `-1`? `ab[-1][-1] = EMPTY;` writes out of bounds and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do you read input from file and overwrite it in the next loop?

Comment: How do I make it so that it doesn't overwrite?

Comment: Another vital programming skill is **breaking a difficult problem into smaller, easier problems.** We can divide this problem into reading the file into the array, and printing the contents of the array. Pick one, and we'll focus on that.

Comment: Remove the second loop containing `ab [i][j] = EMPTY;`. That would also solve the problem with out of bound access.

Comment: Thanks . How can I make it so that it prints the white spaces without showing ASCII characters? Currently it is printing 20 characters on every column and some ASCII characters at the bottom of the column. How can I make it so it prints 15 columns for every Odd row?

Comment: There are two nested loops that print all seats. In the outer loop check if the current row number is even. If it's even print 20 seats for this row. If it's odd print 15 seats for this row. You should do the same for reading the input file. Currently you are reading seats into the wrong position.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow! There is a small mistake in your code, but overall this is pretty good if you're new!

First, you need to distinguish odd numbered rows with even ones. This can be easily fixed by adding an `if` statement, and having different loops. (Alternatively, if it is even, you can set x to be 5 instead of 0)
In order to change your file, you will also need to export to the file. Let's say a customer orders row x seat y. At the end, consider adding something along these lines:

```
ofstream out;
out.open("seats.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        if (i % 2 && j == 15) // 0 is false, 1 is true
        {
            break;
        }
        if (i == x && j == y) // assuming these numbers start from 0
        {
            out << "* ";
        }
        out << ab[i][j] << " ";
    }
    out << endl
}
```

Of course, you still need to make sure the seat isn't taken before selling, but here's what you've asked for. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. However when I run it it prints ASCII and not hashtags that are in the text file.

Comment: @JohnBull Can you elaborate on what you mean when it prints ASCII?